how to go to the same fragment of an activity from another acitivity while returning?

I created an activity as mainActivity and create navigation bar to navigate to other 4 distinct screen or fragment. In one of the fragment name settingFragment, i created a change language button which help to intent to another activity(languageActivity) but when i return back to main activity from languageActivity with back button it redirect me to homeFragment instead of settingFragment where i left. Is there a block code i am missing to happen that...

settingFragment

LinearLayout changelanguage = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutChangeLanguage);
changelanguage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LanguageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
});

languageActivity

ImageButton backButton = findViewById(R.id.Back_Button);
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  // To clear all the stack activity
startActivity(intent);
onBackPressed();
}
}); 


You are clearing all stack activity which will also clear MainActivity and then you are calling onBackPressed().
So, what's happening here is the MainActivity will recreate and you will get Homefragment.
You should avoid Intent part and simple call onBackPressed() only.
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
//Just simply call this
onBackPressed();
}
});


If you just want to go back and don't need an intention, just use onBackPressed() directly.
That's because HomeFragment is the first fragment in your activity. So when you restart your activity then your first fragment is attached. If you want to go to another fragment you can send a value in your intent so you can decide your fragment and your stack.
